# Android datePicker get date values

Tags: android

Hi i have this code for datePicker in android :

```
final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        Button btnDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
        btnDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                dpd.show();   
            }
        });
    }    
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {    
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" +year , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
    }
}
```

I want to set the TextView with the date Values picked by the user, how can I set it?

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date which is received in `onDateSet()` callback as you wish.
Let's say you want the date in `29/05/2016` format, then in that case you need to use -

```
tv.setText(getString(R.string.day_month_year, dayOfMonth, monthOfYear + 1,year));
```

where string `day_month_year` is declared in `strings.xml` like this -

```
<string name="day_month_year">%1$s/%2$s/%3$s</string>
```

Comment: Ok solved it... tnx! TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(getString(R.string.day_month_year, dayOfMonth, monthOfYear + 1,year));

Comment: You don't need to initialize your `TextView` in `onDateSet()`. Declare it outside any method like this - `private TextView tv;` and initialize it in `onCreate()` like this -  `tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv); `

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you.